# Is the Toyota 2ZRU engine the same as the 2ZR-FAE?

Tags: engine, toyota

I've bought a used Toyota Verso (AR2, manufactured in March 2012 in Turkey based on VIN) having a motor/engine code like 2ZRUxxxxxx, but I can't find any information on this type of engine. It is a 1.8l/1798cc gasoline/petrol based engine, but not sure about the specs. I'm based in Europe, the car I bought was sold in Germany. I did find the specs for 2ZR-FAE. Are these the same thing? Why there's no mention of 2ZRU in official documentations?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Answer (score 0):

This [article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Toyota_ZR_engine#2ZR-FAE) has many relevant specs for that engine.  To quote from there:

> The Toyota 2ZR-FAE is a DOHC, 16-valve, 1.8 L (1,798 cc) this engine
> adopts the Valvematic system. This all-new engine is progressively
> replacing the 1ZZ-FED and 2ZR-FE engine in most applications. Variants
> of this engine produce 104–110 kW (139–148 bhp) and 171–175 N⋅m
> (126–129 lbf⋅ft) of torque. Compression ratio is 10.5:1 and redline is
> at 6600 rpm. The engine consumes 5–10% less fuel than the 2ZR-FE
> depending on the application.[4]
>
> A special version of the 2ZR-FAE was introduced by Toyota in 2016 for
> the Taiwanese version of the Toyota Sienta. Unlike the original
> 2ZR-FAE, this version was created by simply adding the Valvematic
> system to the standard 2ZR-FE engine used in the Toyota Corolla Altis
> sold there, resulting in total power of 140 PS (103 kW; 138 hp) at
> 6200 rpm and a peak torque of 172 N⋅m; 127 lbf⋅ft (17.5 kg⋅m) at 4000
> rpm.

Comment: Thanks! I've clarified my question/title: I did find the specs for 2ZR-FAE, but I'm unsure whether it's the same thing as my engine having the motorcode starting with 2ZRU.

Comment: The article shows only one engine configuration for the 2012 Verso.

Answer (score 0):

The part numbers for the block assembly are the same for the corolla and xd, so the 6% difference in hp and less than 2% difference in torque likely are a product of the differences in intake and exhaust layouts.

Having driven supercharged, turbo, and 2ZR swapped Yaris, I would definitely say that the 2ZR is the best choice for a daily driver, if you can track one down reasonably.

I wouldn't be surprised if the difference was caused by all the additional parts that they add onto our cars to meet the emissions standards here in north america, esp California.